# AS3 - MouseWheelDown listener

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events

Is there any way to detect if the mouse wheel is held down? I need to pan my scene while the middle button or mouse wheel is pushed down (I thought holding the mouse wheel down was the same as middle mouse button, but it aint working).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Though I never used it there's `MIDDLE_CLICK` event which works only in AIR apps. Does your app run in browser or on desktop?

Also, just my 2 cents, it's so damn inconvenient to use scrollwheel button in an application. Each time I am forced to do that in some 3D modelling tool I want to smash my monitor. I'd use just shift/alt/ctrl + mouse1/mouse2.

Comment: Thanks, I tried MIDDLE_CLICK, but it didnt work here. Guess I'll just leave it be then.. =) Shift + M1 is already implemented as pan. I just wanted to let the user have more options :)

Comment: Good thing it's just 2 cents. Hope you didn't smash your monitor. I'm all in favor of using the middle mouse button (while depressed) for zooming in 3D. Left: rotate, right: pan, middle: zoom. Modifier keys to either adjust the speed or restrict to certain directions. But those are my cents.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying out this:

```
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (ASnative(800, 2)(1)) { 
trace ("You have pressed or depressed the left mouse button");
}
}
```

this detects the left mouse... if you substitute the argument (1) with (2) you get the right mouse button so...

```
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
if (ASnative(800, 2)(2)) { 
trace("You have pressed or depressed the right mouse button");
}
}
```

and if you put in a (4) you get the middle mouse or often the wheel button...

```
this.onEnterFrame = function() { 
if (ASnative(800, 2)(4)) {
trace("You have pressed or depressed the middle mouse or wheel button");
}
}
```

Source: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=68209

PS: I would suggest not using the middle mouse or wheel button because not everyone has a middle mouse button. So if you still want the usability of a middle mouse button, please adjust your functions accordingly so a person without a middle mouse button can still pan the canvas.

EDIT:

Ok, I made a booboo! Didn't catch it had to be for AS 3.0.
The support for the middle/right mouse button click is no longer available in AS 3.0.
Atleast not directly.

One way to do it is using JS to detect the mouse button that's being pressed and then giving that variable as a string into Flash.

How to detect a mouse click in JS:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

How to put this variable into Flash: (ExternalInterface)
http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/External+Interface

Or you can do it directly through a hack in AS 3.0: (limited browser & OS support)
http://flashpunk.net/forums/index.php?topic=2549.0

DEMO: http://www.shinyhappypixels.com/punk-forums/clicky-hook/

Comment: Thanks.
I'm programming in Flash Builder.
I need to include to ways to pan my view. The first is already working, and that is when you hold the shift key while pushing left mouse button and drag. But we have another software where they use the middle mouse button, so I'd like to include that too. And if they don't have middle mouse button, they can use the shift drag method.. =)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with as3, came across this so here it is:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

function handleMouseWheel(event:MouseEvent):void {

if ((event.delta > 0 && box_mc.y < 270) || (event.delta < 0 && box_mc.y > 0)) {

box_mc.y = box_mc.y + (event.delta * 3);

}

}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleMouseWheel);
```

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? And what exactly is box_mc supposed to be?..........

Comment: box_mc is a movieclip